# multiple classes - how do i target just one button?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to change background color, etc. of a submit button

```
 = submit_tag("Submit", class: "btn btn-sm btn-navbar")
```

I see multiple classes here, and was wondering how this works.

I changed color of `btn-sm` but found that it doesn't do anything. I tried `btn-navbar` and it worked this time, but found that that also changes other buttons.

If I want to change background color, etc. of just the submit button, how do i achieve that?

Comment: Add one more class - btn btn-sm btn-navbar yourclass

Comment: If you want to change color of this particular button and no other button on all the pages, target it's id. However it is more likely that you will want some other buttons to have the same color, in that case add an extra class like `orange-btn` and target it.

Comment: In addition to what luis and broi have said, if you are targetting a class, you will need to make sure it is either more specific than other selectors (in the case of your `btn-sm` not doing anything, I think this may be a case of specificity) or use the `important` rule (which I recommend against as it will make maintenance harder further down the line)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class `change-color`

```
= submit_tag("Submit", class: "btn btn-sm btn-navbar change-color")
```

In the CSS

```
.change-color{
  background-color: #123456 !important;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This didn't work...  What could be the reason/how could I fix it?

Comment: Hi! I clicked the checkmark on the left but it says i need to earn 15 reputation to publicly display my vote... let me know if there's anything else i can do!

Comment: Hmm ok so this worked for one button, but it's not working for other buttons - what could be the reason for this?

Comment: would much appreciate your help!

Comment: You need to add `change-color` class to other buttons also

Comment: I want to style each button differently, so wanted to add diff classes to each button.  your suggestion (adding a class + adding !important) worked for one button, but it's not working for other buttons... not sure why. what could possibly be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

When styling, it is always a good idea to check the generated html (view source in your browser.) The input button generated probably looks something like this:

```
<p id="parentid" class="parentclass"> (or some other container element)
    ...
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-navbar" ... />
    ...
</p>
```

As others point out, if you want to target a specific element, the way to go is to add an additional class. I imagine that something like this:

```
<%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-sm btn-navbar myclass" %>
```

yields

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-navbar myclass" ... />
```

in css you can style this like

```
.myclass {color:pink}
```

however, if for some reason you can't add classes, or you don't want to, there are other options:

```css
input[type="submit"] {color:pink} /* only targets submit buttons */
.parentclass>input {color:pink} /* only targets inputs in a specific element */
#parentid>input {color:pink} /* only targets inputs in a element */
#parentid>:nth-child[2] {color:pink} /* only targets the 2nd child element in the parent */
```

also, keep in mind that multiple rules may apply to your button. There are several ways to make the btn-sm take precedence:

input.btn.btn-sm.btn-navebar {color:pink} /* more specific definitions take precedence */
.btn-navbar {color:pink !important} /* the first matching important rule takes precedence */

also, keep in mind that multiple rules may apply to your button. There are several ways to make the btn-sm take precedence:

```css
input.btn.btn-sm.btn-navebar {color:pink} /* more specific definitions take precedence */
.btn-navbar {color:pink !important} /* the first matching important rule takes precedence */
```

Comment: input[type="submit"] {color:pink} didn't work....  also other suggestions i.e. .parentclass>input {color:pink} #parentid>input {color:pink} #parentid>:nth-child[2] {color:pink} seem to be targeting inputs, not buttons?

Comment: tried .btn-sm {color:pink !important} but didn't work either - really stuck here, appreciate help

Comment: @user2277916 submit buttons actually are input elements with type="submit". Looks like everybody here think there's a css precedence problem, but may be it's problem with your ruby on rails code, I know nothing about RoR, but should't it look like `:class => 'btn btn-sm btn-navbar'` instead of `class: "btn btn-sm btn-navbar"`. It would be nice if you provide more code or a link to the page with this problem

Comment: Again: When styling, it is always a good idea to check the generated html (view source in your browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your new style for `.btn-sm` worked but you didn't see any changes because you have style for `.btn-navbar` that goes AFTER `.btn-sm` in HTML.

If you keep new CSS for `.btn-sm` and change `class: "btn btn-sm btn-navbar"` to `class: "btn btn-navbar btn-sm"` you'll see your new style had applied.

But that's not the case. If you want to apply some style to one particular element of the page you should assigned an ID to this element OR you can add another class to it and in the future you'll be able to add this class to other elements. Just don't forget that this new class or ID should be placed after all classes that already exist.

Comment: I tried class: "btn btn-navbar btn-sm", but didn't work... also assigning class as others suggested didn't work either.... what else could i do? thank you